# What intermediate representations can be used to reason about concurrency?

Tags: compiler, concurrency, computer-science

I am trying to better understand what would be required for a compiler to be able to make intelligent choices regarding concurrency on behalf of the programmer. I realize that there are many difficult aspects of this problem for instance:

- Ensuring that there are no race conditions
- Ensuring that the code to be run concurrently won't have side effects that impact the semantic meaning of the code
- Deciding whether the overhead from spinning up threads is worthwhile given the degree of parallelism available in the code

My understanding is that the two major intermediate representations used in modern compilers are static single assignment for procedural and object oriented languages and continuations passing style for functional languages. Reasoning about any of the problems listed above seems difficult using these intermediate forms. Even languages that should in theory have the best chance at automatic parallelization (pure functional languages like Haskell with a guarantee of no side effects) have made limited progress on this front.

So my question is really what intermediate representations have been used to try and tackle this problem? Are there other representations that have been used in academic research that I am not aware of that are better suited to this task? Is this problem one that fundamentally has to be resolved by the compiler front end by manipulating the abstract syntax tree before compilation reaches an intermediate representation?

Comment: If you write your code in a functional way, you won't have to worry about race conditions or side-effects.

Comment: This does not quite answer your question, but you might be interested in [*Process Calculi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_calculus) which can be used to reason about concurrent code. The best known example might be the [*Pi Calculus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-calculus). However, [automatic parallelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_parallelization) is still a largely unsolved problem and best tackled by designing languages specifically to provide the compiler with certain guarantees, or by using special annotations.

Comment: The [paper that serves as the backdrop for Intel Concurrent Collections (CnC)](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/7/2/9/0/c/42856-CnC_eight_patterns.pdf) lists eight fundamental concurrent patterns, such as Producer-Consumer. These concurrent patterns in turn depend on a number of properties, such as immutability and side-effect-free. (I would appreciate if anyone can summarize that paper and post as an answer here.)

Comment: One of the theoretical tool is called "Dynamic Single Assignment (DSA)", built on top of SSA.

Comment: @rwong: can you provide an explicit reference?

Comment: In addition to immutable values, there is unique references to mutable data.  Automatically parallelizing requires more space/latency hints than we typically have; in the form of latency/throughput/memory constraints.  If you are processing audio samples, you don't want to queue up thousands of samples just to maximimally parallize throughput - because each sample has a minimum latency requirement.  You also don't want to use thousands of times as much memory just because that might maximize throughput or latency.

Answer (score 5):

One would assume that modeling concurrency explicitly in the intermediate representation (IR) was a necessary requirement.  So one answer would be, "any IR used for sequential programs with the addition of some concurrency operations", e.g., "fork and join", "parallel x y".   Adding these makes it possible to reason about some kinds of concurrency, but not necessarily easily.  Nor is it obvious how to ensure certain properties (data-race freeness) without going all the way to a fully functional representation (which makes it hard to model parallelism usefully).

Arguably [Colored Petri Nets (CPNs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloured_Petri_net) are a good choice for representing programs with concurrency. (Tokens in CPNs are "colored" [have a type] and can carry values; "transitions" into states can perform arbitrary arithmetic on incoming tokens to produce a possibly differently colored token with computed value in the "place").   If you think about places as being computed results and transitions as modelling operators (including a special one to access memory), this gives you what amounts to a data flow graph with which to model programs.  You can easily use this to give a formal interpretation to classic compiler representations such as triples [operator,input1,input2,output].

There are lots of tools to analyze such CPN graphs, including computing properties such as deadlock-freeness, boundedness of token counts in places, etc. Heirarchical CPNs let you model functions and procedures and the notion of "calls".

What these representations do not clearly do, is make it easy to reason about where one could parallelize an application.   Trivially, two subcomputations can be parallel if they side-effect no shared operands ( which is why some folks love functional programs/representations). If your program representation models a shared memory, you can model it as monolith and get the usual set of troubles about reasoning about interactions on the shared memory, including aliased addressing, etc.   One way to avoid this is to treat memory as isolated chunks with the larger program state being some (tree-like) assemblage of these; you can arguably pass these chunks around in your intermediate representation.  There is no interaction between two parallel computations if they don't share chunks (e.g., memory subtrees).